# Posicionar un mdPanel dentro de un mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, material-design

Estoy intentando posicionar un **`mdPanel`** debajo de un *TextBox* dentro de un dialog pero el `mdPanel` siempre me aparece en la esquina superior izquierda del `mdDialog` ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

El *HTML* del componente:

```
<div class="hide">
    <div id="dialogSpotlight" class="md-dialog-container">
        <md-dialog>
            <md-toolbar class="md-accent">
                <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                    <h4>@ResourceManager.GetLiteral("SpotlightComponentSearch")</h4>
                    <span flex></span>
                    <md-button class="md-icon-button">
                        <md-icon class="material-icons" ng-click="$ctrl.closeDialog()">close</md-icon>
                    </md-button>
                </div>
            </md-toolbar>
            <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" layout-padding>
                <md-input-container id="spotlight-component-dialog-input-search-container" flex="80">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <input placeholder="Buscar" ng-model="$ctrl.searchedText" ng-keypress="$ctrl.keyPress($event)" ng-keyup="$ctrl.keyUp($event)" />
                </md-input-container>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button" flex="20">
                    <md-icon class="material-icons">search</md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </div>
            <div>
<!--Aquí va el elemento al que intento vincular el mdPanel -->
                <md-content class="spotlight-component-dialog-panel-container">
                    <div id="spotlight-component-dialog-panel-content"></div>
                </md-content>
            </div>
        </md-dialog>
    </div>
</div>
```

La configuración del `mdPanel`:

```
function openPanel(position) {
    var config = {
        attachTo: angular.element(document.body),
        templateUrl: 'templates/shared/spotlightPanel',
        controller: PanelController,
        controllerAs: '$panelCtrl',
        position: position,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        escapeToClose: true,
        focusOnOpen: false,
        zIndex: 89,
        locals: {
            data: {
                properties: $ctrl.properties,
                demands: $ctrl.demands,
                people: $ctrl.people,
                propertiesOwners: $ctrl.propertiesOwners,
                demandsOwners: $ctrl.demandsOwners,
                peopleCategories: $ctrl.peopleCategories,
                searchedText: $ctrl.searchedText
            },
            showProperties: $ctrl.showProperties,
            showDemands: $ctrl.showDemands,
            showPeople: $ctrl.showPeople,
            showWheel: $ctrl.showWheel,
            callbacks: {
                propertyCallback: $ctrl.propertyCallback,
                propertyOwnerCallback: $ctrl.propertyOwnerCallback,
                demandCallback: $ctrl.demandCallback,
                demandOwnerCallback: $ctrl.demandOwnerCallback,
                peopleCallback: $ctrl.peopleCallback,
                peopleCategoryCallback: $ctrl.peopleCategoryCallback
            }
        }
    }
    if ($spotlightComponentPanelRef != null) {
        $spotlightComponentPanelRef.close();
    }

    $ctrl._mdPanel.open(config)
        .then(function (result) {
            $spotlightComponentPanelRef = result;
        });
}
```

La función que realmente abre el `mdPanel`:

```
function checkAllSearched($ctrl) {
    var allLoaded = true;
    var relativeElementID = "spotlight-component-dialog-panel-content";

    for (var i = 0; i < $ctrl.allSearched.length; i++) {
        if ($ctrl.allSearched[i] == false) {
            allLoaded = false;
        }
    }

    if (allLoaded) {
        var position = $ctrl._mdPanel.newPanelPosition()
        .relativeTo("#" + relativeElementID)
        .addPanelPosition($ctrl._mdPanel.xPosition.ALIGN_START, $ctrl._mdPanel.yPosition.BELOW);

        $ctrl.openPanel(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, y después de leer cientos de artículos he llegado a la conclusión de que no es posible hacer lo que intentaba. He tenido que tirar por otra vía totalmente distinta puesto que era un callejón sin salida.

El contenido del panel lo he hecho componente y es el que tengo que situar en los puntos donde quiera mostrar los datos